# How can I convert an int to BSTR

Tags: visual-c++

I would like to convert an int to BSTR. I'm using createTextNode in MSXML which accepts BSTR. How can I do that please?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not efficient but first convert to a string and then you can simply convert that (untested):

```
std::wstring convertToString(int value)
{
    std::wstringstream ss;
    ss << value;
    return ss.str();
}

_bstr_t theConverted(convertToString(42).c_str());
```

Comment: What is Converted on the last line?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm very new to C++

Comment: Converted is just a variable name. Call it what you want. Just renamed it to remove any confusion.  Also there was a couple of slight bugs to fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = 123;
_bstr_t bstr = (long)number;
```

([Source](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=122576))

Answer (score 0):

[Data Type Conversion Functions [Automation]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b69504cf-6c80-4de1-a26e-9281ab848c71%28VS.85%29#functions_to_convert_to_type_bstr) (MSDN), see "Functions to convert to type BSTR" section.